# MVC5 project structure: Not sure how it should flow

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, n-tier-architecture

I am about to create a new ASP.NET web application using MVC5 w/ Telerik Kendo UI and I want it to be structured properly. I found this Telerik [sample project](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-saleshub-demo) on GitHub but the structure confuses me.
**There are 3 layers:**
Client layer
Core layer
Data layer

I don't understand why there is a repositories folder at the Data layer and then another repositories folder with all related interfaces at the Core layer. Shouldn't anything repository related be in the Data Layer? And anything Business Logic related be in the Core layer?

I am also using EF6 DBFirst with an .edmx file in my data layer so would I still want a repositories folder in mine the way the sample project is structured?

My overall goal is to do something similar to what they are doing here but with EF6 Db First. I still want similar layers and I want to end up using ViewModels and Dependency Injection to pass data to my views.

I have been trying for weeks now to come up with a nice MVC5 EF6 DBFirst Ninject(for IoC) project structure with a Data Layer, Business Logic Layer, and UI Layer. Are there any good examples out there or can someone please explain how it should be done?

Comment: There are already a million questions exactly like this on SO.. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=MVC+project+structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well what I do is create three Projects for the N-Tier Architecture, and another 1 called Common:

1. **The Web MVC Project**

   Views work as Normal MVC Project
   Each Controller has a constructor with Business Provider Parameters passed in using Ninject.
2. **A BusinessProviders Project**

   This Project contains multiple classes that deal with all my Business Rules, e.g. if I have a website where I have jobs and users I will have two Providers UsersProvider, JobsProvider etc.
3. **Data Layer (DAL)**

   This Project contains the edmx file itself. and also classes that interact with the entities.
4. **Common**

   This contains all other Classes, Enums, Helpers that are used throughout the Solution

So basically my data flow through the application is:

View --> Controller --> BusinessProvider --> Data Access Class --> Entities (Database)

View <-- Controller <-- BusinessProvider <-- Data Access Class <-- Entities (Database)

The reason I use this approach is that I find it much more clean to write code and reuse it. Also it helps in IoC (In my case Ninject).

I have wrote a simple blog post on this here (I will write another blog post for Ninject integration in next few days): http://myseesharp.blogspot.co.uk/

**EDIT:** Links to Ninject with N-Tier:

http://myseesharp.blogspot.co.uk/2015/01/ninject-with-n-tier-mvc-application.html

http://myseesharp.blogspot.co.uk/2015/01/ninject-with-n-tier-mvc-application_1.html

Comment: Unbelievable response. I have been waiting for something like this for months now. Although I have a few questions. In your blog post you create 3 classes suffixed with Dal. Are these doing the same things as repositories? Don't most people create an ICarsRepository and then a CarsRepository class that has common db functions? Are you basically placing any functions necessary to access the db in these DAL classes? And finally do we need to use Interfaces at all? I am assuming in the IoC version you will.

Comment: In IoC you will have to use the Interfaces, you are correct. 
Yes in my View repository and DAL are the same thing. They are common functions reading and writing to the Database. So e.g. in PassengersDAL you can write: GetPassengersByName(string name)

Comment: Or in your case you can create this Function in Repository

Comment: So I would add an edmx file to my DAL and then create a folder to hold my classes and basically place all data access functions in each class. I am going to make an attempt of setting this up with IoC tonight. If you actually make an IoC version that would be awesome.

Comment: @user2272527 See my Edit, Hope it gives you an idea of how to do it.

Comment: WOW thanks so much for putting that together so fast. So you are using Ninject in both the UI layer and Business layer? Also I am a little confused about the Dto folder within your Common library. Will I be able to use this with DbFirst since the classes are auto generated in the DAL do I just mimic the properties in my Dto classes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68048/discussion-between-user2272527-and-dawood-awan).

Comment: I added Ninject to my MVC5 project and created a Infrastructure/NinjectDependencyResolver.cs where I will add my business bindings and in my AppStart/NinjectWebCommon.cs in RegisterServices I register my NinjectDependencyResolver.cs to be my Dependency Resolver. Although, I am debating on whether to add bindings within my BLL to my DAL. Is this necessary, I believe I heard some people are against it. Also, if I were to do this do I need to do it the way you did in your example and reference Ninject from BLL? Sorry I have never seen dependency injection the way you did it in your 2 examples.

Comment: The Architecture is that we can't reference the DAL in our WebProject, we have to create the Bindings for DAL in BLL. You can create the Bindings in your project in any way you think is better for your solution. That's the beauty of programming you can program the same loic 10 different ways and the result will still be the same. It depends on how you want to do it